# Solution explorer doesn't show my projects in MS VC++ Express 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio express 2013 edition and when I create a win32 console project my solution explorer does not show any of the normal folders (External Dependencies, Header Files, Resource Files, Source Files). The solution explorer is visible on the screen, it is just empty. Since I can't select the solution I cannot add new items to it (I can't add any source files).

Everything has been working on this machine just fine before but now it does not. Is there some option that I have accidentally set to hide the solution in the solution explorer?